# How can you calculate base voltage of a transistor when there are biasing resistor and a resistor between 2 input terminal

Tags: transistors

I just get to know about transistor a little. Here is my question
[image]

As you can see that here the transistor is configured to be an amplifier in common emitter mode. R1 here is the bias resistor. What I don't know is how Vb can be calculated. Suppose the input voltage is known already but here the input voltage is affected by R1 and R2 that make Vb is different from input voltage. Also, R1 is connected between b and Vcc that also affect Vb.

I learn how to calculate voltage, current and resistance (or impedance) of parallel and cascade circuit but this case look strange and KCL can't be apply here also (or it's just me who don't know how to apply it). Of course, in real life I can use voltage measure device to know its value but I am talking about math here.

Comment: The questioner here, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125747/common-emitter-not-amplifying?noredirect=1#comment251517_125747 does a nice job of calculating the bias point for a similar circuit.  Any good book on electronics should have something similar.

Comment: sorry but I am just go to simple circuit. The circuit in your link is so complicated to me right now

Comment: Oh sorry.. he calculates values for the CE stage only.  (ignore the first half of the circuit.)  Do you have any basic electronics books?

Comment: I try to find some book that can teach me about circuit but can't find any suitable. I find this website recently (few days ago) http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/ but it mention how common emitter work only so I'm trying to find how common collector and common base work.

Comment: "Art of Eelctronics" is the classic, but maybe a bit much for a beginner.  I recently purchased "Practical electronics for inventors" (~$22) which is at a lower level.  There's a few things I don't like, but in general it's good.

Answer (score 1):

You must analize the Thevenin's equivalent circuit:

[image]

where

$$
R_{th} = \dfrac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1 + R_2}
$$

and

$$
V_{th} = \dfrac{V_{CC}}{R_1+R_2}\cdot R_2
$$

then, the equivalent circuit

[image]

where \$V_b\$ is \$V_{th}\$ and \$R_b\$ is \$R_{th}\$

Then, you can write KVL, for the input circuit:

$$
V_b = i_b\cdot R_b + V_{BE} + i_b\cdot (\beta + 1) \cdot R_E
$$

Answer (score 1):

The simplest calculation is to assume the base current is 0, then

Vb = \$Vcc\frac{R2}{R1+R2}\$ and

Ve = Vb - 0.7V.

Once you know Ve you know the emitter current

Ie= Ve/Re, and since the base current is assumed to be zero, you can find

Vc = Vcc - Ie * Rc.

That is valid if \$\frac{R1R2}{R1+R2}\$ << \$\beta Re\$

If you want more accuracy you have to solve this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f44xTG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where

Rx = \$\frac{R1 R2}{R1+R2}\$

V1 = \$Vcc\frac{R2}{R1+R2}\$

Ry = Re  \$\beta\$

Which is easily solved as

Vb = \$(\frac{V1}{Rx} + \frac{V2}{Ry}) \frac{Rx Ry}{(Rx + Ry)}\$

Then Ve = Vb - 0.7V

Ie = Ve/Re

And Ic = Ie (1-(1/\$\beta\$))

so finally,

Vc = Vcc - Ie Rc  (as before)

Answer (score 0):

You would really need to know the output resistance of the input voltage source to Vb. Without it you can't really know for sure. If an op-amp or a similar amplifier stage drives Vb, then the output impedance should be quite low. If it's low, then it's as if you're applying a true voltage source to Vb. In that case, all of the bias resistors really don't matter because the input voltage will drown out their effect.

Alternately, something like this is commonly driven by a capacitively coupled source. This means that DC will be blocked and AC will pass through. In that case, the bias resistors you see in your diagram are what will determine the DC set point of Vb is. In that case, what the others post is correct.

If your input voltage source has an output impedance somewhere in between the two extreme cases I give (0 and infinite impedance) then you'll need to add that into the circuit and start crunching the numbers/equations.

Some off the cuff rules that usually work so long as your bias resistors allow enough current flow generally means that you treat R1 and R2 as a voltage divider and find an approximate DC setpoint from that.